# How can I get the start and end address of a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, memory-address

With the "address-of" operator unary &. I can know the starting address of the struct.

```
 struct Point {
     int* data;
     int x;
     int y;
 };

 struct Point offCenter = { 1, 1 };
 struct Point* offCentreAddress_start = &offCenter ;
```

How do I determine the end address (offCenterAddress_end)?

Comment: I'm not sure structs are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, but if so, you can probably whip something up using `sizeof`.

Comment: If a *data is malloc to say 20. How can we still be sure?

Comment: `p.data = malloc(20)` does not affect the address of `p.x` or `p.y`, and it doesn't affect data immediately past the end of `p`.

Comment: @UrsaMajor `data` is a pointer to an integer; its size is constant, regardless of how much allocated memory you point it to.

Comment: To expand a bit: The `malloc`ed memory goes into the heap, rather than the stack. If you declared array members in your struct, that *would* go into the stack, but the arrays would be a fixed size. If you defined two structs, with different sized array members, then they would be different sizes... I see your confusion -- pointers to dynamically allocated memory are often conflated with arrays -- but they are not generally interchangeable.

Comment: oh. I remember now. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You do not need `sizeof`.

```
struct Point offCenter = { 1, 1 };
struct Point* offCentreAddress_start = &offCentre;
struct Point* offCentreAddress_end = &offCentre + 1;
```

By definition, pointer arithmetic is done in multiples of the pointed type's size. That's how array indexing works.

About your comment : pointing `data` at `malloc`'ed memory (or anything else) won't change `data`'s size : it's just a pointer.

Comment: Two little nitpicks: 1) It points to the first location *beyond* the end and 2) possible padding is regarded as part of the struct. 1) is probably what is intended and 2) probably doesn't matter, depending on the use-case

Comment: Can you give example sample code to illustrate that?

Comment: @FelixPalmen just picked up OP's variable name :)

Comment: @UrsaMajor are you asking Felix or me ?

Comment: @UrsaMajor: Imagine struct definition like `struct foo { short x; char desc[13];};` - it will be an odd number of bytes long, and as most platforms require objects to start on even addresses, there will likely be some "padding" bytes between two instances of the struct.  So the address of the byte following the end of the instance isn't necessarily the address of the byte that starts the next instance.

Comment: You could get the address of the byte immediately following the end by using a similar method: `int *end = &offCenter.y + 1`.

Comment: @JohnBode isn't that much better because you could always use that, whereas this answer would need to change &offCenter + n depending on n?